# AngularJS on IIS - Browser Cache doesn't return updated page template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iis-7

I am developing a B2B that is now in production.
The problem is that when I update the application on IIS 
the html files of the template are not updated. 
After I clear the cache of the browser everything gets updated.

How can I avoid IIS to cache the pages of the templates?
Or more generally how can I do to always have the most recent server files?

Thanks 
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

When you update the files on the html , it means you are applying some patch which eveytime you have your updated number like build number or patch number.
You have to append this patch number or build number at the end of each page.
You have to set this build number in global service and embed at the last of each html template.

For example.
At start:

```
build_number =1; 
your_template ='content.html?'+buildnumber
```

At second iteration:

```
build_number =2;
```

This way you always get updated htmls everytime you apply some changes on server. Usually this build number is final svn build number. Hope you get my point.

Comment: Thanks,
I imagined something like this.... but how to implement is?
I mean where do I have to insert the build_number in my html file?
what is build_number variable? is there documentation?

Comment: You have to store this build number in your configuration file. When you load first page of your application, you read this build number from config file and store as a variable in global service of angular service. now whenever you get the template , attach this number in your template URL.